# print using mPDF from joining table

Tags: php, mysql, printing, row, mpdf

table_1

```
+------+--------+
| code | name   |
+------+--------+
| 1056 | Alex   |
| 1057 | Rudy   |
| 1058 | Brian  |
+------+--------+
```

table_2

```
+------+------+
| code | rate |
+------+------+
| 1056 |    9 |
| 1057 |    7 |
| 1058 |    8 |
+------+------+
```

based on these tables I want to make a table with joining them.

the first file, show.php

```
echo "<td><a href=print.php?code=$row[code]>Print....</a></td>";
```

the second file to print the joining table, print.php

```
//...

$code = $_GET['code'];
$res = mysql_query("select table_1.code, table_1.name, table_2.rate from table_1, table_2, where table_1.code = table_2.code");

//...

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    $a=$row['code'];
    $b=$row['name'];
    $c=$row['rate'];

$html .= '<tr><td>'.$a.'</td><td>' .$b. '</td><td>'.$c.'</td></tr>'; 
}
$html .= '</table> </center>';

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html,2); 
$mpdf->Output('print.pdf','I');
exit;

//...
```

but the result show all the rows :

```
+------+--------+------+
| code | name   | rate |
+------+--------+------+
| 1056 | Alex   |    9 |
| 1057 | Rudy   |    7 |
| 1058 | Brian  |    8 |
+------+--------+------+
```

how to make the result just show one row like this? :

```
+------+--------+------+
| code | name   | rate |
+------+--------+------+
| 1056 | Alex   |    9 |
+------+--------+------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now Check it

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT table_1.code, table_1.name, table_2.rate FROM table_1 INNER JOIN table_2 ON table_1.code = table_2.code WHERE table_1.code ='".$code."'");
```

Comment: now there's no row in result, only the field name.
I also try with >> where '$code' = table_2.code and table_1.code = '$code' but no rows too.

Comment: same result, no rows, only field name even though I add query at the last line with AND table_2.code = '".$code."'

Comment: I already test your query in MySQL and it works in one row, but not from PDF result.

Comment: Ok it works too in PDF result, I just found some little bit failure on my editing code. Thanks :)